# Function return table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

I'm trying to create a function that return a table variable.So firstly i get data from Table1 and put it in another table variable. Here i want check if this variable isempty the function return the parameter result else return the result of the table variable 
The function script is bellow :

```
USE[DATABase1]
GO

IF OBJECT_ID (N'CodeFunc', N'TF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.CodeFunc;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION CodeFunc ( @Code nvarchar(4) , @Table nvarchar(40) = '' )
RETURNS @VirtualDAT TABLE
       (
        RowID      INT    IDENTITY ( 1 , 1 ),
        Code   nvarchar(400)
       )
    AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE     @CodeM  nvarchar(400)
        DECLARE     @imax       INT SET         @imax = @@ROWCOUNT 
        DECLARE     @i          INT SET         @i =  1

        DECLARE  @SelectDAT TABLE
           (
            RowID      INT    IDENTITY ( 1 , 1 ),
            Code   nvarchar(400)
           )
        INSERT @SelectDAT
            SELECT Code FROM   table1
                WHERE  table1.id = 41

        IF(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SelectDAT))
            BEGIN
                WHILE (@i <= @imax)
                BEGIN 
                     SELECT  @CodeM = Code FROM @SelectDAT WHERE  RowID = @i
                     INSERT INTO @VirtualDAT(Code) VALUES (@CodeM)

                SET @i = @i + 1
                END
            END

        ELSE 
            INSERT  INTO @VirtualDAT(Code) VALUES (@Code)

RETURN
END
```

So this script works without put it inside function.

And i test this function like this :`SELECT * FROM dbo.CodeFunc( 'toto',Default )` the result is :
 `IF(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SelectDAT))` no record returned
esle the result is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As VR46 says. The @@ROWCOUNT will be set to 0 because there is no query before it. Any code executing in a function happens as a seperate set of queries. It was probably returning a value outside the function because you had previously used the query window for another unrelated query

You could re-factor this function quite dramatically. Look below, @@ROWCOUNT will work here as it is just after the insert query and will definitely have a value based on the insert.

I have not been able to test this, but I think something like this should do the same job.

```
USE[DATABase1]
GO

IF OBJECT_ID (N'CodeFunc', N'TF') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.CodeFunc;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION CodeFunc ( @Code nvarchar(4) , @Table nvarchar(40) = '' )
RETURNS @VirtualDAT TABLE
       (
        RowID      INT    IDENTITY ( 1 , 1 ),
        Code   nvarchar(400)
       )
    AS 
    BEGIN

        insert into @VirtualDAT
        Select Code from table1 where table1.id = 41

        if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        begin
            INSERT  INTO @VirtualDAT(Code) VALUES (@Code)
        end
RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are assigning `@imax` with `@@ROWCOUNT` right after `declaration` of variable will be initialized with `zero`.

From [**`MSDN`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187316.aspx) `@@ROWCOUNT`

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.

If am not wrong you need to assign value to `@imax` after the `insert into..select` query.

```
INSERT @SelectDAT
            SELECT Code FROM   table1
                WHERE  table1.id = 41
SET @imax= @@ROWCOUNT
```

You can do the same in `SET BASED APPROACH` without using `while` loop.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Codefunc (@Code  NVARCHAR(4), 
                          @Table NVARCHAR(40) = '') 
returns @VirtualDAT TABLE ( 
  rowid INT IDENTITY ( 1, 1 ), 
  code  NVARCHAR(400)) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      IF EXISTS (SELECT code 
                 FROM   table1 
                 WHERE  table1.id = 41) 
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO @VirtualDAT 
                        (code) 
            SELECT code 
            FROM   table1 
            WHERE  table1.id = 41 
        END 
      ELSE 
        INSERT INTO @VirtualDAT 
                    (code) 
        VALUES      (@Code) 

      RETURN 
  END
```